# Indent forwards a tree structure

Tags: org-mode, indentation

I have such a structure in my org note

```
**** pstree
     * ~ $ pstree -aps 26955
systemd,1 splash
  └─systemd,1947 --user
      └─gnome-terminal-,2710
          └─bash,1775
              └─emacs,25135
                  └─bash,26955
~ $ pstree --arguments --show-pids --show-parents 26955
systemd,1 splash
  └─systemd,1947 --user
      └─gnome-terminal-,2710
          └─bash,1775
              └─emacs,25135
                  └─bash,26955
```

[image]

I want to indent the codes region forwards but get  (mark the region and press tab)

```
**** pstree
     * ~ $ pstree -aps 26955
     systemd,1 splash
     └─systemd,1947 --user
     └─gnome-terminal-,2710
     └─bash,1775
     └─emacs,25135
     └─bash,26955
     ~ $ pstree --arguments --show-pids --show-parents 26955
     systemd,1 splash
     └─systemd,1947 --user
     └─gnome-terminal-,2710
     └─bash,1775
     └─emacs,25135
     └─bash,26955
```

but I want the whole block keep its structure.

Is it possible to get it done?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `org-indent-mode`, which will indent the display of `org-mode` files in Emacs. Your structure isn't a tree to `org-mode`, so it won't treat it as such. If you want `org-indent-mode` to be enabled by default, you can add `(setq org-startup-indented t)` to your init file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-mode` does not recognize your structure but you could indent it manually.

To indent a region with `N` space characters:

> Select the region to indent and use `C-u N indent-code-rigidly`
>
> for example: `C-u 8 indent-code-rigidly` for 8 spaces.

To indent a region with tabs:

> Select from the beginning of first line to the beginning of the last
>   one and use `C-x r t C-i RET`